# How to do the Birthday Paradox looping

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, birthday-paradox

I have to do the birthday paradox program as an assignment for school. I got the program to run but seem to hav trouble getting the correct answer. I think it's a problem with my loops in the `check_birthdays` function.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<time.h>


void check_birthdays (int birthdays[], int num, int count=0)
{
     for (int i=0; i<num; i++) //to check each person in the group
     {
         for (int j=i+1; j<num; j++) //against every other person in the group
         {
             if (birthdays[i]==birthdays[j])
                 count++; 
         }
     }
     //print out the number of people with ame birthday
     cout<<"The number of people who share their birthday is "<<count;
}

int main()
{
    //create a variable for an inputted number of people
    int people, count;
    cout<< "Please input a number of people: "<<endl;;
    cin>>people;

    int birthdays[people];

    //input check
    if (people<50 || people>100)
        cout<<"Error, please try again.";
    else
    { //fill that array with random numbers
        for (int i=0; i<people; i++)
        {
            srand (time (NULL));
            birthdays[i]= rand()%365;
        }
        check_birthdays (birthdays, people, count); //send to the next function
    }
}
```

Comment: @Phillipp: the homework tag is [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: what answer are you expecting? Might I suggest that you start with a known input instead of random, so that you can fine tune your algorithm before testing on "real" data (that also makes it easier to debug)

Comment: Call `srand` only once, at the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you mean by "it doesn't work", I'd guess that you probably want to replace a matched birthday with some invalid value so that it will not match again as you move forward in your loop.

One more hint, there is no need to call `srand()` every time.

Comment: "no need" rather understates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `main()`, the variable `count` is not initialized and it is passed to `check_birthdays()`, so the result can be anything.

Also, in C++ when the size of an array is decided at runtime, the normal solution is to use `std::vector`.